how arrange every attributes in a parent level attributes array
const allItems = await findAndPaginate(CartItems, req.query, {
            attributes: [
                ["cart_items_id", "cartId"],
                ["cart_item_mrp", "mrp"],
                ["cart_item_discount", "discount"],
                ["cart_item_no_of_sessions", "sessionCount"],
                ["cart_item_status", "status"],
                ["cart_item_emi", "emi"],
                ["cart_item_created_at", "createdAt"],
            ],
            include: [
                {
                    model: User,
                    as: "createdBy",
                    // attributes: []
                    attributes: ["name"]
                },
                {
                    model: CartPaymentLog,
                    attributes: [
                        ["cart_payment_log_id", "paymentLogId"],
                        ["cart_payment_log_payable_amount", "payableAmt"],
                        ["cart_payment_log_created_at", "createdDate"],

                        [Sequelize.literal(`
                            CASE WHEN \`CartPaymentLogs\`.\`cart_payment_log_payment_invoice_id\` IN (SELECT payment_capture_invoice_id from payment_capture) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
                            `), "paidStatus"]
                    ],

                },

            ],
            where: {
                cart_item_lead_id: leadId,
                cart_item_status: {
                    [Sequelize.Op.in]: isWishList ? ['4'] : ['0', '1']  
                },
                cart_item_deleted_status: '0',
            },
            order : [["cart_item_created_at","desc"]]
        })

I need to arrange all the inner attributes fields into its parent attributes array
Need : I have already wrote a function to handle with search,filter,sorting etc(findAndPaginate) which uses findAndCountAll method of Sequalize
findAndPaginate fn only works if the attributes are in the outermost attributes array
I tried by using Sequalize.col() and Sequalize.literal() , but its not working since the above generated sql is in weird way
SELECT `CartItems`.*,
       `createdBy`.`userID` AS `createdBy.userID`,
       `createdBy`.`name` AS `createdBy.name`,
       `CartPaymentLogs`.`cart_payment_log_id` AS `CartPaymentLogs.cart_payment_log_id`,
       `CartPaymentLogs`.`cart_payment_log_id` AS `CartPaymentLogs.paymentLogId`,
       `CartPaymentLogs`.`cart_payment_log_payable_amount` AS `CartPaymentLogs.payableAmt`,
       `CartPaymentLogs`.`cart_payment_log_created_at` AS `CartPaymentLogs.createdDate`,
       createdBy.name AS `CartPaymentLogs.createdBy`,
       CASE
           WHEN `CartPaymentLogs`.`cart_payment_log_payment_invoice_id` IN
                  (SELECT payment_capture_invoice_id
                   FROM payment_capture) THEN TRUE
           ELSE FALSE
       END AS `CartPaymentLogs.paidStatus`
FROM
  (SELECT `CartItems`.`cart_items_id`,
          `CartItems`.`cart_items_id` AS `cartId`,
          `CartItems`.`cart_item_mrp` AS `mrp`,
          `CartItems`.`cart_item_discount` AS `discount`,
          `CartItems`.`cart_item_no_of_sessions` AS `sessionCount`,
          `CartItems`.`cart_item_status` AS `status`,
          `CartItems`.`cart_item_emi` AS `emi`,
          `CartItems`.`cart_item_created_at` AS `createdAt`,
          `CartItems`.`cart_item_created_by`
   FROM `cart_items` AS `CartItems`
   WHERE ((`CartItems`.`cart_item_lead_id` = '200481'
           AND `CartItems`.`cart_item_status` IN ('4')
           AND `CartItems`.`cart_item_deleted_status` = '0'))
   ORDER BY `CartItems`.`cart_item_created_at` DESC
   LIMIT 0,
         10) AS `CartItems`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `user` AS `createdBy` ON `CartItems`.`cart_item_created_by` = `createdBy`.`userID`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `cart_payment_log` AS `CartPaymentLogs` ON `CartItems`.`cart_items_id` = `CartPaymentLogs`.`cart_payment_log_cart_items_id`
ORDER BY `createdAt` DESC;


Did you try raw: true ?

My aim is to put all attributes into top level attributes array, raw : true doesn't affect on this
